# NVD3 and changing data

Tags: nvd3.js

I am trying to create a few visualizations of data. What I would like to do is to create a drop-down menu to change the chart. As of now, my data is coded into the html file. What I plan to do is to move the data into separate JSON files that can be called via a menu that will change the chart. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17737563/nvd3-tooltip-not-showing-up-after-changing-dataset), but it's for CSV files. Is there something similar to this for JSON files?

```
<div id='chart57b8c4fde7' class='rChart nvd3'></div>     

<script type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      drawchart57b8c4fde7()
    });
    function drawchart57b8c4fde7(){  
      var opts = {
        "dom": "chart57b8c4fde7",
        "width":   725,
        "height":    550,
        "x": "NAME",
        "y": "Total",
        "group": "Type",
        "type": "multiBarChart",
        "id": "chart57b8c4fde7" 
        },
      data = [
       {
       "NAME": "ONE",
      "Type": "A",
      "Total":      4 
      },
      {
       "NAME": "TWO",
      "Type": "A",
      "Total":      2 
      },
      {
       "NAME": "ONE",
      "Type": "B",
      "Total":      5 
      },
      {
       "NAME": "TWO",
      "Type": "B",
      "Total":      5 
      }
      ]
    var data = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d){
        return opts.group === undefined ? 'main' : d[opts.group]
      })
      .entries(data)

    nv.addGraph(function() {
      var chart = nv.models[opts.type]()
        .x(function(d) { return d[opts.x] })
        .y(function(d) { return d[opts.y] })
        .width(opts.width)
        .height(opts.height)

     d3.select("#" + opts.id)
      .append('svg')
      .datum(data)
      .transition().duration(500)
      .call(chart);

     nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
     return chart;
    });

    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use D3s' JSON reader

```
d3.json("data.js", function(data) {
   alert(data.length)
});
```

Or use jQuery to read the JSON

```
$.getJSON("data.js", function(json) {
    console.log(json)
}).done(function() {
    console.log("json loaded");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("error loading json");
});
```

**Here is a List on how to [Load External Resources](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests)**

Hope it helps.